# reading a GML file with networkx (python) without labels for the nodes

Tags: python, networkx, graph-modelling-language

I have a long GML file (Graph Modelling Language) that i am trying to read with Networkx in Python.
In the GML file, nodes don't have label, like this:

```
graph [
  node [
    id 1
  ]
  node [
    id 2
  ]
  edge [
    source 2
    target 1
    ]
  ]
```

I get an error when reading the file:
G = nx.read_gml('simple_graph.gml')

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetworkXError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b1b319a08668> in <module>()
----> 1 G = nx.read_gml('simple_graph.gml')

<decorator-gen-319> in read_gml(path, label, destringizer)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.pyc in _open_file(func, *args, **kwargs)
    218         # Finally, we call the original function, making sure to close the fobj.
    219         try:
--> 220             result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
    221         finally:
    222             if close_fobj:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.pyc in read_gml(path, label, destringizer)
    208             yield line
    209 
--> 210     G = parse_gml_lines(filter_lines(path), label, destringizer)
    211     return G
    212 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.pyc in parse_gml_lines(lines, label, destringizer)
    407             raise NetworkXError('node id %r is duplicated' % (id,))
    408         if label != 'id':
--> 409             label = pop_attr(node, 'node', 'label', i)
    410             if label in labels:
    411                 raise NetworkXError('node label %r is duplicated' % (label,))

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.pyc in pop_attr(dct, type, attr, i)
    397         except KeyError:
    398             raise NetworkXError(
--> 399                 "%s #%d has no '%s' attribute" % (type, i, attr))
    400 
    401     nodes = graph.get('node', [])

NetworkXError: node #0 has no 'label' attribute
```

I see that it complains because the nodes don't have labels. From the documentation of GML i thought that labels were not obligatory (maybe i'm wrong?). Would there be a way to read such a file without labels? Or should i change my gml file?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use `id` attribute in GML for labeling nodes, you can designate the label attribute for the `nx.read_gml` argument as follows.

```
G = nx.read_gml('simple_graph.gml', label='id')
```

Comment: Can you know any solution to convert this gml file to txt or csv or other formats?

Comment: @AMICHARADAVA GML file is already a text file. You can open it in a text editor and save it in *.txt or *.csv file. If you want to change GML to a specific text format (usually, this is the case), you need to make your own parser.