# node #0 has no 'label' attribute?How come it happens

Tags: python, networkx

I am new user of python and networks, I have trouble to read some data from .gml file
My IDE is Spyder,Anaconda,and OS is macOS
 is 
I follow the instruction online ,here is my code ,here is the [Dataset](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/karate.zip)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.read_gml('karate.gml')

print (nx.info(G))
```

then the complier shows "node #0 has no 'label' attribute". How could it happens

Comment: Networkx [have](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.social.karate_club_graph.html) the karate graph. Try: `nx.karate_club_graph()`

Comment: @Lucas I just request by reading third party data by my instructor :(

Comment: I think we'll need to see karate.gml before we can answer the question.

Comment: @Joel hi Joel I already update

Comment: hmm, this is the `karate.gml` from Mark Newman's webpage...  I see the same error.  I wonder if this is a bug in networkx, perhaps something introduced when it upgraded to version 2.0?  You could maybe try networkx 1.11.

Comment: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3157

Comment: repeat question, go through this link for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200898/reading-a-gml-file-with-networkx-python-without-labels-for-the-nodes

Answer (score 7):

If you are using that popular karate.gml datasets, try the code below:

```
G = nx.read_gml('karate.gml', label = 'id')
```